# How to insert comma separated fileds into a table

Tags: java, sql

Kindly note that I want to insert the below values:

```
EDR,10063012186648,908410101,00000004322380023224651,2014-02-01,2014-02-28,28,803.00,0.00,0
```

in the below table

```
FIELD1  FIELD2  FIELD3  FIELD4  FIELD5  FIELD6  FIELD7  FIELD8  FIELD9  FIELD10
```

Note that the the fields are stored in a text file, until now I wrote a code that will read the fields from the text file and print them, but I did not find a way to store them in the database.

```
String target_dir = "//mw1-msfs-003/IT/temp";
File dir = new File(target_dir);
File[] files = dir.listFiles();
for (File f : files) {
   if(f.isFile()) {
      BufferedReader inputStream = null;
      try {
         inputStream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
         String line;

         while ((line = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {
             System.out.println(line);
         }
      } finally {
         if (inputStream != null) {
             inputStream.close();
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Please advise how to store the data into a database?

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify your code instead of only reading try forming the Insert queries and execute the queries by using prepare statement of Java.

The following link would be of help

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-insert-records.htm

Comment: This interesting, but still that link does not tell how to insert comma seperated values from a text file into a database

Comment: You want to insert entire comma separated values only in one field? If that is the case your database structure won't follow concepts of Normalization

Comment: No that is not the correct way, I need to store all the data seperately into the database

Comment: What is the problem in splitting the entire string with "," and forming an insert query string and preparing statement?

Answer (score 0):

Check if your DB has a command for populating tables directly from CSV files. MySQL has [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) command, PostgreSQL and derived databases, like Vertica, have [COPY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-copy.html) command. This commands allow to set delimiters (in you case it's comma) and escape characters. Using of this approach is much simpler and faster comparing with reading and loading files in an application.

You can find example of using COPY in PostgreSQL [here](http://www.gistutor.com/postgresqlpostgis/10-intermediate-postgresqlpostgis-tutorials/39-how-to-import-or-export-a-csv-file-using-postgresql-copy-to-and-copy-from-queries.html).